# Applicable alternatives to Dropdown when there are only 2 Options

Tags: website-design, webforms

Attached below is a concept for a entry field which leads to a Donation form. The intention is to have the user enter their donation amount in their preferred currency (EUR or USD) then proceed to the form by clicking next.

However, I am not sure of the best way to switch between EUR and USD while keeping the UI simple, making it clear that there are two options and also making it usable on mobile.

See my concept below :

[image: Currency Dropdown Closed]

[image: Currency Dropdown Open]

Comment: Hi, what is the +100 Euros chip for, and does it change to USD if the user changes to USD? Also, do you have any more vertical space to work with, or does the solution need to stay in the bounds of this space?

Comment: @Izquierdo The 100 euro chip was a concept to be able to set the value of your donation +100 each time you click it, was just an idea. I suppose I could remove the top line of text has it isn't critical, what did you have in mind?

Comment: It's a cool pattern, I was wondering if it was clickable because that might affect solutions that would use buttons for currency indicators (can one have too many buttons?)

Comment: I think it is fine as it is. More so if you can ensure the appropriate default is automatically set based on the current user's culture/locale settings. That way they should never need to change it... but it's there in the rare instances where they do need to change it.

Comment: @musefan That's a really good suggestion, using a back-end solution to reduce required interaction from the User. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually thought that this would be a common problem solved by a toggle button of some sort (especially since it is on mobile) but I think normally on e-commerce platforms you are dealing with any number of acceptable currencies so the dropdown is more practical.

However, if I was to have a guess at how people are solving this problem (from some of the [currency switch plugins](https://www.secomapp.com/shopify-currency-switcher-app/) I have seen for shopify or wordpress) it would be to stick with the dropdown or use a context switch toggle (where the button represents the state of the data field).

[image]